# python subprocess remote find -exec filename with space

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssh, subprocess

So I have a remote Linux Server and would like to run a Python Script on my local machine to list all files and their modification dates in a specific folder on that remote server. That is my code so far:

```
command = "find \""+to_directory+'''\"* -type f -exec sh -c \"stat -c \'%y:%n\' \'{}\'\" \;'''

scp_process_ = subprocess.run("ssh "+to_user+"@"+to_host+" '"+command+"' ", shell=True, capture_output=False, text=True)
```

Now running the command

```
find "/shares/Public/Datensicherung/"* -type f -exec sh -c "stat -c '%y:%n' '{}'" \;
```

on the server itself works fine without any error.

But as soon I use a subprocess to run it remotely over ssh it has a problem with a file in a folder with spaces: "/shares/Public/Datensicherung/New folder/hi.txt" with a space in it:

```
stat: can't stat '/shares/Public/Datensicherung/New': No such file or directory
stat: can't stat 'folder/hi.txt': No such file or directory
```

I know it is messed up, but that is the best solution I could build.
I would like to stick with subprocess and ssh but if you have a better solution feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `shell=True` you are invoking *three* shell instances, each of which requires a layer of quoting. This is possible to do, of course, but there are many reasons to avoid it if at all possible.

First off, you can easily avoid the local `shell=True` and this actually improves the robustness and clarity of your Python code.

```py
command = "find \""+to_directory+'''\"* -type f -exec sh -c \"stat -c \'%y:%n\' \'{}\'\" \;'''

scp_process_ = subprocess.run(
    ["ssh", to_user+"@"+to_host, command],
    capture_output=False, text=True)
```

Secondly, `stat` can easily accept multiple arguments, so you can take out the `sh -c '...'` too.

```py
command = 'find "' + to_directory + '" -type f -exec stat -c "%y:%n" {} +'
```

The optimization also switches `+` for `\;` (so the `sh -c ''` wrapper was doubly useless anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue happening because malformed command string. For purpose of comunication with Unix shell was craeted [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shlex.html) module. So basically you wrap your code with [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shlex.html) and then pass it into `supbrocess.run`.

I don't see the actual final cmd to call but you could split it to proper command with `shlex.split` by yourself.

From your example it would be something like:

```
from shlex import join

cmd = join(['ssh',
 f'{to_user}@{to_host}',
 'find',
 f'{to_directory}*',
 '-type',
 'f',
 '-exec',
 'sh',
 '-c',
 "stat -c '%y:%n' '{}'",
 ';']))

scp_process_ = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=False, text=True)
```

Also, you maybe want to play around with `shell=True` option.